# Pullback of hyperplane under morphism associated with divisor is linearly equivalent to divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal projective variety and $D$ a divisor on $X$. Take the complete linear system $|D|$ and a basis of it $\{s_0,...,s_n\}$. The morphism associated with $D$ is defined as $\Phi(P)=[s_0(P):...:s_n(P)]$ from $X$ to $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Our course notes says the pullback under $f$ of a Cartier divisor $\{(U_i,d_i)\}$ is defined as $f^*(div(d_i))=div(f^*(d_i))$ on an affine open cover $\{V_{ij}\}$ of $f^{-1}(U_i)$.

Take the hyperplane $V(X_i)$, which is locally $div(\frac{X_i}{X_0})$ on $U_0$ one of the affine open. Then $\Phi^*(div(\frac{X_i}{X_0}))$ is locally $div(\frac{f^*X_i}{f^*X_0})=div(\frac{s_i}{s_0})$. Now I am confused about a few things.

0. Is the definition of pullback correct? How to come up with $\{V_{ij}\}$?
1. The notion of linear equivalence, is it global?
2. Having answered 1, how to continue to show $D\sim \Phi^*(V(X_0))?$

Comment: What do you mean by "global" in question 1?